# What is the best way to implement a inter-qwebview communication?

Tags: qt, qwebview

Overview:

I am trying to create a PoC application that mimics WebIntents-like feature. 
So, in my Qt application, I create two QWebviews launching two different webApps. Now let's call them apps A and B.

Scenario:

- Main Application creates two QWebViews each launching an App i.e. AppA, AppB.
- App A is programmed to fetch some data via AJAX, automatically.
- App B also needs  part of that data. AppB simply displays a button (HTML) called .
  **Note**: Since, AppA already has that info, I would like  the AppB to invoke a JavaScript API which was injected into    it's(appB) DOM by means of addToJavaScriptWindowObject() method call when the QWebView was launched.
- App-A completed the Ajax Call and indicates the completion in its WebView.
- User clicks the button  in AppB,
- App B invokes that JavaScript API i.e. fetcData({source: "AppA");
- Now the control is in the QT-world:

**Question**: the Control is in the context of AppB, How should I communicate with the WebView in AppA -- i.e. AppB asks AppA: hey AppA, please give me that data that you have fetched?

Can Signals and Slots help me here? Or should I use some other form of IPC.

I read this page:  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html, but I still didn't get a hint for a solution for my problem.

Another related **question**: Are QWebViews created in their own threads ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just `emit` some sort of `signal` from AppB that basically says, "Hey, I finished fetching my data if anyone wants it" or am I missing something? It would happen at the end of `AppB::fetchData()`.

All you have to do after that is connect any interested objects to that signal.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question, i just fixed that.

Comment: The AppB doesn't need such a signal just yet. Since it is a Proof-Of-Concept. I didn't make the AppA to emit the "data-ready" "finished-fetching" type signals. So the user (i.e. me) would click a button on the AppB to fetch data through the QT. This would be done upon seeing that the QWebView of AppA is populated with the fetched data.

Comment: So in this scenario, the AppB needs to get the handle of WebView of AppA and call a method AppB::fetchData(in QT-CPP). This method in turn needs to call the JavaScript code of AppB's QWebView which has the data! I am not totally sure how to to accomplish this.

Comment: Since control is back in the MainWindow, you could simple pass the address of AppA to `AppB::fetchData(MyWebView* app_ptr)`, then use `app_ptr` to access any members of AppA that you need.

Comment: If you did connect a `dataFetched()` signal from AppA to a slot in AppB, you can accomplish the same thing in AppB's slot using QObject::sender();

Comment: Thanks. I still have one lingering question in the back of the mind: In the above example, are both QWebViews created in the same thread-context? Are the QWebviews simple UI-widgets without any execution context of it's own? I am guessing the answers for both of the questions are "Yes". I saw this similar post (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/14426) seem to indicate the QWebview would always be on the main-UI thread. Could you please comment? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: QWebView, [like all UI elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086142/qt-signaling-across-threads-one-is-gui-thread), runs on the main thread. You can bypass this by realizing that QWebPage is a QObject that can be [moved to another thread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread) if needed.