# Qt : qt cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread - Why

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, callback

I am developing an application with Qt whereby I want to update my GUI from another unrelated class with functions executing in a different thread.

I registered a callback function from the Qt GUI class to the other class using standard C++ constructs std::function and std::bind.

On trying to execute the GUI callback function from the other class, my program crashes with "**qt cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread**".

My questions are, what is happening here exactly. Why is it not permissive to communicate between two threads like this. Is it possible to resolve this in some way , or does Qt just not allow other unrelated functions to update the GUI in this way ?

For information , I am using portaudio libraries on windows. It executes a callback in a different thread. When I receive audio, I try to update my GUI.

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638251/how-to-emit-cross-thread-signal-in-qt) [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086142/qt-signaling-across-threads-one-is-gui-thread) but they are rather old. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382820/how-to-leverage-qt-to-make-a-qobject-method-thread-safe) doesn't quite fit the question but is modern and should answer the question.

Comment: You might try asking the same question about Java Swing.  The inventors of Java first created a multi-threaded windowing toolkit called AWT, but making it work right turned out to be a much harder problem than they expected.  Eventually, they gave up on AWT, and created a new, single-threaded toolkit called Swing.  Their reasons for making Swing single threaded probably are valid for any window toolkit in any language.  I don't remember where I read about it, but you probably can find  it using Google.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking the cleanest way for me possibly is to start a QThread running  on my GUI when I push a button or whatever. The QThread will then poll flags of my other class and update the GUI accordingly. I normally don't like polling, but do you think this is my best (or only) option?

Comment: Sounds like precisely the scenario for `Qt` [queued signal/slot connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html).

Comment: Your difficulty seems to stem from HOW you're connecting your GUI classes in the main thread to your non-Qt classes in the worker thread. Could you post that portion of code, please?

Answer (score 7):

You're probably being thrown off by the "send events" phrase. In Qt, this phrase has a strict technical meaning. Namely:

- to **send** events means to use `QCoreApplication::sendEvent`, which then immediately invokes `QObject::event` on the receiver. **It is an error to send events when the sending and receiving threads are different**.
- to **post** events means to use `QCoreApplication::postEvent`, which posts the event to the receiving object thread's event queue. The `QObject::event` on the receiver is invoked later by the receiver thread's event loop.

When objects live in different threads, you're not allowed to **send** events, only to **post** them. This points to the underlying cause of your issue/

Any method you access on a `QWidget` or a derived class must be accessed on its `thread()`, i.e. the main thread. Everything inside of `QWidget` can use `sendEvent` freely as the sending thread and receiving object's thread are identical by contract. By calling `QWidget` methods from the wrong thread, you break that contract by indirectly using `sendEvent` and thus fail.

Only methods that you yourself have implemented and are thread-safe can be called from other threads - and they can't use `sendEvent`.